# createsamples unable to open file info.txt

Tags: opencv

```
E:\Softcomputing\tools\temp\createsamples.exe -info positive/info.txt -vec data/vector.vec -num (number of positive images) -w 50 -h 80

Unable to open file: positive/info.txt

Done. Created 0 samples
```

Can you tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: You're evidently on Windows:  try backslashes in paths?  Maybe the tool doesn't understand forward slashes in Windows paths?  Thus, `positive\info.txt`, `data\vector.vec`.

Comment: Thanks but still it can't open the txt file.

Comment: You're sure your path is correct? (the folder `positive` should be in ``E:\Softcomputer\tools\temp\`` ) Also, make sure that `info.txt` is formatted correctly - should be `img_location #objectsInFrame r1 r2 r3 r4` for each line

Comment: yes I am sure of it. even the format is correct. Is there a chance that there is some problem with createsamples.exe or that I am using windows 10